# Sufficient conditions for system of quadratic matrix equations to have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given matrices $A, B, C, E, F \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $E \succ 0$, classify matrices $A, B, C, E, F$ such that matrices $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are  unique solutions for the following equation.

\begin{aligned}
&XFY+XA+BY+C=0\\
&XY+E=0
\end{aligned}

Comment: what do you mean by the statement that "matrix" $E>0$?

Comment: for $n=1$ it is obvious that has two different answer, but for $n>1$ it has always a unique answer

Comment: What I mean is E is positive definite

Comment: If it has two solutions for $n=1$, then there are cases in which it also has two solutions for $n>1$: simply take multiples of the identity matrix for $A,B,C,E,F,X,Y.$

Comment: Take $A=B=C=F=0$ and $E>0$. Then $XY+E=0$ has more than one solution.

Comment: Hi all I have edited the question. thank you

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What is the context?

Comment: this problem is what I have faced in my reasearch. matrices $A,B,C,E$ are optimum values comming from a convex optimization. However I am trying different random values for these matrices I will receive a unique answer for X and Y . but the cases that our friends suggested are right there is some cases that we receive different answers but , it has often a unque answer, which I wanted to see is the classification of $A,B, C, F, E$ are aligned with my convex optimization or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E$ is invertible, $X,Y$ too. Thus we may write the system in the unknowns $X,Y$ as follows

$Y=-X^{-1}E$ and $-XF+XAE^{-1}X-B+CE^{-1}X=0$.

Notice that the second equation is the GENERAL standard Riccati equation

$(*)$ $XPX+XQ+RX+S=0$ (choose $E$ symm. $>0$, $F=-Q,A=PE,C=RE,B=-S$).

Generically (randomly choose $P,Q,R,S$), $(*)$ admits  $\binom{2n}{n}$ complex solutions. Here, you consider only the real solutions and you want only one. It's very difficult to  find a NSC for the equation to admit a single real solution. It's much easier to give a sufficient condition.

Consider, for example, the CAR Equation

$A^TX+XA-XBR^{-1}B^TX+Q=0$

Though generally this equation can have several solutions, it is usually specified that we want to obtain the unique stabilizing solution, if such a solution exists.

Example with a unique complex solution (which is real!)

$X\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}X+\begin{pmatrix}-1&2\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}X-\begin{pmatrix}-3&5\\-2&2\end{pmatrix}=0$.

Comment: For the OP. I read your answer. If you are satisfied by my answer, then accept it; that is, give it the green chevron.

Comment: How can I accept it, can you show me?

Comment: It's ok. You gave the green chevron. Thanks.